# How to make a GridViewColumn readonly/disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, gridviewcolumn

I have a reference to a `GridViewColumn` in my xaml code as `RuntimeColumn` but I am not able to disable it or set it to readonly programmatically. I will need to do this at runtime without databinding.

I tried:

```
this.RuntimeColumn.IsEnabled = false;
this.RuntimeColumn.ReadOnly = false;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a cell template?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information ?

Comment: Sorry guys just saw it. Yes I have a CellTemplate that adds checkboxes for each row. But I want one of the GridViewColumns to be enabled/disabled based on a property. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set an EventSetter with Loaded Event, and in your code behind put the following

```
private void GridViewColumnHeader_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        GridViewColumnHeader columnHeader = sender as GridViewColumnHeader;
        Border HeaderBorder = columnHeader.Template.FindName("HeaderBorder", columnHeader) as Border;
        if (HeaderBorder != null)
        {
            HeaderBorder.Background = HeaderBorder.Background;
        }
        Border HeaderHoverBorder = columnHeader.Template.FindName("HeaderHoverBorder", columnHeader) as Border;
        if (HeaderHoverBorder != null)
        {
            HeaderHoverBorder.BorderBrush = HeaderHoverBorder.BorderBrush;
        }
        Rectangle UpperHighlight = columnHeader.Template.FindName("UpperHighlight", columnHeader) as Rectangle;
        if (UpperHighlight != null)
        {
            UpperHighlight.Visibility = UpperHighlight.Visibility;
        }
        Thumb PART_HeaderGripper = columnHeader.Template.FindName("PART_HeaderGripper", columnHeader) as Thumb;            
        if (PART_HeaderGripper != null)
        {
            PART_HeaderGripper.Background = PART_HeaderGripper.Background;
            PART_HeaderGripper.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow; // override the size curser
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is very new to me. Which one retrieves a particular GridColumnView by name, say "RuntimeColumn", set as x:Name="RuntimeColumn"?

Comment: in the xaml, set the HeaderContainerStyle to a style, and set the <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="GridViewColumnheader_Loaded"/>

Comment: @Joan Venge, only the column that you want disabled, needs to be styled with the "Loaded" event.